# How to use Nested TypeBuilder before Enclosing Type is Created/Completed?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, cil, system.reflection

I am currently working on a compiler for a custom programming language to msil using `System.Reflection.Emit` and I've come across a problem that's been bugging me for days. I am creating a type which acts as a module, so it contains type and function definitions. This means, that I am making a type and then referencing it as, for example, the type of a local variable in a function later. This is where the problem lies, because the type that I defined earlier has obviously been completed, but when I call `ILGenerator.DefineLocal([type])` it throws a `TypeLoadException` saying that the enclosing type could not be loaded. I assume, this is because it has not been created/completed yet.

How would I go about solving this issue while still keeping the defined type a NestedType of the enclosing module-type?

Comment: You need to pass in the `TypeBuilder` of the dynamic type, not the `Type` you got back from `.CreateType()`. If that's not the solution, show more code with exactly what you're doing (the details for Reflection.Emit are often finicky and not always obvious).

Comment: @JeroenMostert This works, thank you. But now I get the same error when calling `ILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructor)`, even though I make sure to get the constructor from the TypeBuilder (TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(types))

Comment: Yeah, more code would be needed to sort out that one. If the type is not yet complete, you'll need to use the `ConstructorBuilder` you got from `DefineConstructor` (likewise, for any "not yet complete" definition, you need the `*Builder` instances and other placeholders), otherwise `GetConstructor` should work for both `Type` and `TypeBuilder`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh, I don't call `DefineConstructor` yet, because I haven't implemented defining Constructors yet. Does it not work with the "default" one that is there when not defining any? Because `GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)` does return a constructor...

Comment: If you don't define any constructors, the default constructor will be generated automatically, and if you got that back from `.GetConstructor()`, then the type should be complete and `newobj` should also work with that reference. Again, though, if you have code that doesn't work, post that code -- SO is about questions and answers, not about interactive debugging sessions.

Comment: Sorry, [here](https://pastebin.com/7ma2XGEZ)'s the code of the class that's causing the error right now. Or should I open a new Question?

Comment: It would be fine to edit this one, and include the *relevant* code, and particularly where and how it actually fails -- questions should be self contained. The code you've linked to is "too interesting" -- we don't know how `GLFunction` works, for starters, so we're likely missing the relevant bits where you're actually going wrong. See [mcve] -- in the process of making one you often find the problem (and if you don't, you will at least have the smallest bit of code that reproduces it directly).